# How do I integrate VisualFoxPro DB with Magento

Tags: database, magento, visual-foxpro, payflowpro, sage-erp

I am an IA working on a Magento/VFP integration solution.

Does anyone know if VisualFoxPro has a method by which Magento can read the VFP datadase?

These DB calls will also need to integrate with SagePro and PayFlow

Answer (score 0):

You can read VFP data using ODBC or OLE DB. So, if Magento supports either of those, you're in business.

Answer (score 0):

Magento is currently MySQL only. The planned Magento 2.0 [will be SQL'99 compliant](https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/Framework+Changes+from+1.x+to+2.x#FrameworkChangesfrom1.xto2.x-UnifiedResourceModels) and so work with any supporting DBMS.